# Loop through an array consisting of numbers and strings, but return sum of only numbers ActionScript

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, loops, for-loop, foreach

This should be pretty basic, but there aren't too many tutorials for ActionScript out there. JavaScript is close, but I can't find how to do this either. I want to be able to have a mixed array consisting of string and number data types, loop through the array and get the sum of the numbers while ignoring the strings.

Example Array:

```
var myArray:Array = [13, 10, "blah", 5, "eh", 10, "Twenty", "Thirty"];
```

Answer (score 8):

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
var total:Number = 0.0;
for (var i:int=0; i<myArray.length; i++)
{
    if(myArray[i] is Number)
        total += myArray[i];
}
trace(total);
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. I had everything correct but the if statement. Thanks!